# Elasticsearch unsupported parameters during indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

Running the following command `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/alpha/_mapping/gremlin -d @company_info_mapping.json`returns a `400` with a message `Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters`.

Here is the mapping file:

```
{
    "settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
    "analysis" : {
        "index_analyzer": {
            "my_index_analyzer" : {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter" : ["lowercase", "mynGram"]
            }
        },
        "search_analyzer": {
            "my_search_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "mynGram"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "mynGram": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 30
            }
        }
    }
  },

  "mappings": {
    "company_info": {
        "properties": {
            "company" : {"type" : "string"},
            "description": {"type": "string"},
            "founded": {"type": "string"},
            "headquartes": {"type": "string"},
            "industry": {"type": "string"},
            "numberOfEmployees": {"type": "string"},
            "size": {"type": "string"},
            "specialties": {"type": "string"},
            "typ": {"type" : "string"},
            "website": {"type" : "string"},
            "domain" : {"type": "string"},
            "link": {"type" : "string"},
            "linkedinId": {"type": "string"},
            "linkedinUrl": {"type": "string"},
            "title": {"type": "string"},
            "people":{"properties":{"email":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"linkedinId":{"type":"string"},"linkedinUrl":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"},"twitter":{"type":"string"},"verifiedEmail":{"type":"string"}}}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that all the description on the error ? Did you look at the elastic-search server side log for the exception ?

Comment: What is gremlin? How did you create the index?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Gremlin is a term I pulled out of hat while trying to setup my cluster and play around with things. The script above is what I used to create the indexes without the `settings` section.

Comment: @RajindRuparathna I'll post the server logs as soon as Im back at my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON above contains both `settings` and `mappings` and you're hitting the `_mapping` endpoint. If your `alpha` index already exists and you want to update its mappings, then you can run the following command with the following content:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/alpha/_mapping/gremlin --data-binary @company_info_mapping.json
```

`company_info_mapping.json`:

```
{
   "properties": {
        "company" : {"type" : "string"},
        "description": {"type": "string"},
        "founded": {"type": "string"},
        "headquartes": {"type": "string"},
        "industry": {"type": "string"},
        "numberOfEmployees": {"type": "string"},
        "size": {"type": "string"},
        "specialties": {"type": "string"},
        "typ": {"type" : "string"},
        "website": {"type" : "string"},
        "domain" : {"type": "string"},
        "link": {"type" : "string"},
        "linkedinId": {"type": "string"},
        "linkedinUrl": {"type": "string"},
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "people":{"properties":{"email":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"linkedinId":{"type":"string"},"linkedinUrl":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"},"twitter":{"type":"string"},"verifiedEmail":{"type":"string"}}}
    }
}
```

If you want to update the settings of your existing index, then hit the `_settings` endpoint with the following:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/alpha/_settings --data-binary @index_settings.json
```

`index_settings.json`:

```
{
"index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
"analysis" : {
    "index_analyzer": {
        "my_index_analyzer" : {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "standard",
            "filter" : ["lowercase", "mynGram"]
        }
    },
    "search_analyzer": {
        "my_search_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "mynGram"]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "mynGram": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 30
        }
    }
  }
}
```